# How to force caller error on calling constructor or type casting?

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, strong-typing

I'm trying to make a "strong typedef" template which would prohibit casting between different types. In relevant part, current (working) code looks like this:

```
template<typename T, typename Tag>
struct strong_typedef_impl {
public:
  //! ---- error struct (for better MSVC diagnostic)
  struct error { friend struct strong_typedef_impl; private: error(){} ~error(){} };

  //! ----  Construction
  /*implicit*/ strong_typedef_impl(const strong_typedef_impl& other) : value(other.value) {}
  /*implicit*/ template<typename U, typename UTag> 
  strong_typedef_impl(const strong_typedef_impl<U, UTag>&) : value() {
    static_assert(false, "One must not cast one strong typedef to another");
  }

  //! ----  Type casting
  /*explicit*/ inline operator T(void) const {return value;}
  template<typename U, typename UTag>
  /*implicit*/ operator strong_typedef_impl<U,UTag>(void) const {
    static_assert(false, "One must not cast one strong typedef to another");
  }

  //! ----  Assignment
  const strong_typedef_impl& operator=(const strong_typedef_impl& other) {
    value = other.value; return *this;
  }
  const strong_typedef_impl& operator=(strong_typedef_impl&& other) {
    value = other.value; return *this;
  }
  //template all-encompassing assignment to avoid implicit casting
  template <typename U> error operator=(const U&) {
    //static_assert(false, "One must not assign anything else to a strong typedef");
    return error();
  }
  //...
};
```

Third assignment operator returns `error` instead of failing by `static_assert` because the project is usually compiled by MSVC compiler from Qt Creator and when it sees `static_assert` fail, it marks only the line with `assert` itself and not the caller code (in best case, this makes someone who got the problem read through compilation logs; in worst case, someone who got the problem just assumes it was my fault). But returned `error` object instead forces the compiler to destroy it within caller code, thus marking the proper line at the price of less informative message.
However, I can't figure out a similar trick for casting. Initially I thought that writing constructor

```
/*implicit*/ template<typename U, typename UTag> 
strong_typedef_impl(const strong_typedef_impl<U, UTag>&, error e = error()) : value() { }
```

would force caller to call `error()`, resulting in an error, but this doesn't seem to be the case.

Does anyone know some way to "trick" compiler into making wrong code on a caller side in this case? Or maybe some other way to get meaningful diagnostic from MSVC compiler?

Comment: Wouldn't [declaring a constructor or operator as deleted](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/function#Deleted_functions) (`= delete;`) cause an error where it is used?

Comment: Huh. Missed the obvious (probably because I can't simply use `=delete;` since one of the compilers doesn't understand it, but I can write compiler-dependent macro). Thank you.